# Вывод данных на страницу

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring, freemarker

При выводе данных в консоль все отображается без пробела, а вот если на страницу появляется небольшое расстояние и затем если в окне пытаться изменить текст то это считается за пробел и нужно вручную удалять так как вылетает ошибка несовпадение типов.
Как убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/bookInfo">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th >Название</th>
        <th >Автор</th>
        <th >Год издания</th>
        <th>Инвентарный номер</th>
        <th scope="col">Количество</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <#list books as book>
    <tr>

           <td > <a href="/bookInfo/${book.id}"> ${book.name}</a></td>
           <td>${book.author}</td>
           <td>${book.year}</td>
           <td>${book.invNum}</td>
            <td>${book.countBook}</td>
       </tr>
       </#list>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно пример кода HTML?

Comment: В коде не хватает одного или несколько тэнов.

Comment: забыл закрыть </form>, так как это часть кода
но даже если просто на пустой странице вывести ${book.year} то разделение все равно есть

Comment: А при чем тут java, простите?))

Comment: на java код написан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался! нужно вызывать переменную заменив $ на #
вот так #{book.year} либо еще работает вот так ${book.year?c}